# Will this kind of bash work as expected?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

MYSQL="/usr/bin/mysql -uroot "

function create_db()
{
    local db_name=${1}

    $MYSQL<<!
    create database IF NOT EXISTS ${db_name};
!
}

###-------------------------tb_bind_userid_xxx-------------------------------------
function create_table_userid
{
    $MYSQL << !
    create table if NOT EXISTS bind_pay.tb_bind_userid_${1}(
        b_userid bigint not null, 
    b_membercode bigint not null , 
  PRIMARY KEY  (b_userid)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
!
}
```

Will `$MYSQL` be persistent across function calls,or reconnect each time?

If it reconnects every time,I don't think `create_table_userid` will work as expected though,because it hasn't specify a database name yet.

Answer (score 2):

Well, because you will be calling the function each time you want to create the table, you will call `mysql` to connect to the database each time. If you want persistent connection, one way is to use a mysql library that is supported by most major programming languages these days, Perl/Python/Ruby/PHP etc. You can make a DB connection, then do whatever stuff you want, then finally close the connection. for example in the documentation of `Python/Mysql`

```
   import MySQLdb
   conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                           user = "testuser",
                           passwd = "testpass",
                           db = "test")
   cursor = conn.cursor ()
   cursor.execute ("SELECT VERSION()")
   row = cursor.fetchone ()
   print "server version:", row[0]
   cursor.close ()
   conn.close ()
```

As you can see, a connection `conn` is opened to connect to database. Then using the connection handle (or rather database handle), stuff are done and then finally, the connection is closed.

Comment: @wireshark, the way it's written in the question, there's a separate process for each invocation of $MYSQL, so it cannot be persistent.

Answer (score 0):

`$MYSQL` is just a variable, so your code *runs* mysql each time it calls one of these functions.

You *can* create a persistant connection to mysql easily enough; just have your program write its sql to output, then pipe the whole results into mysql:

```
(
  create_table "foo"
  create_table "bar"
) | mysql

create_table() {
  cat <<!
create table $1 ....
!
}
```